# Can't connect to MongoDb externally

Tags: mongodb

Some information:

- The port is indeed open(i can bind it to apache2, for example, and access it externally)
- I've tried setting the bind_up parameter to 0.0.0.0, to my localip, etc
- I can access it through my local IP(192.167.10.xxx)
- I didn't isntall mongo with apt-get, just downloaded it and ran mongod

I've spent a lot of time searching and trying different things, anyone has a idea on what could be causing it?

[Mongo runnning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjX9W.png)

edit:

Mongo options: [initandlisten] options: { config: "config.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 8008 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/home/defense/mongo/data" } }

When i try to connect:
[thread1] Failed to connect to 146.164.x.xxx:8008, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused

Port check(also I used to connect to MySql using that same port):
Port 8008 is open on 146.164.x.xxx.

Any ideas?

Comment: If that port is really open, then you can connect it even with telnet and get answer. If not, then check again!

Comment: Hi Giancarllo Rojas; can I offer one piece of advice, about the way you have asked your question? Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your server log, copy and paste or type the actual text into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: The port is really open, I checked with sites that test it and as I said i can make make apache listen to that port and access it externally. 

@VinceBowdren Thanks for the advice, I'll do it next time, sorry for it.

Comment: @GiancarlloRojas You can [edit] your question to include that information without the screenshot; remember, on this site you are encouraged to edit and re-edit questions and answers to improve them as much as possible.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thanks again!